# Stack overflow error with hitTest in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

So, I have a class file for an asteroid, and inside of it, i've used this code:

```
public var ourAsteroid:Asteroid = new Asteroid(stage);
```

To allow the asteroid to become a variable, however when I add in this chunk:

```
public function hitTest(e:Event) : void {
        if (ourAsteroid.hitTestObject(ourAsteroid))
            speed = -speed;


    }
```

I get a #1023 Stack Overflow Error at the Asteroid.As file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ourAsteroid.hitTestObject(ourAsteroid)` is causing the error as it is performing a hit test on itself.

hitTestObject should be performed only against other objects as it will return true if the objects are overlapping. Given the line `speed = -speed` in your comment, I can guess that what you're actually trying to do is make the asteroid bounce off something. If you want it to bounce off the edge of the screen, you just need to test for when the bounds of the object have reached the edge, for example on the horizontal:

```
if(ourAsteroid.x < 0) {
    ourAsteroid.x = 0;
    speed = -speed;
}
else if(ourAsteroid.x > stage.width - ourAsteroid.width) {
    ourAsteroid.x = stage.width - ourAsteroid.width;
    speed = -speed;
}
```

If you want it to bounce off another object, just use a hit test as before: `ourAsteroid.hitTestObject(someOtherObject)`. Note that this is an extremely simple implementation and you will probably see issues such as objects getting stuck in one another, but it'll at least get you started.

Comment: Well, I'm using an array to add multiple asteroids to the screen randomly, and I'm trying to make it to where if those asteroids touch, they bounce off of eachother.

Comment: Then the final paragraph in my answer still stands: you just need to ensure that you're not hitTesting an object against itself. However, overall this will not work: even for basic bounding box collisions you will need to check whether an asteroid touched another on the top/bottom/left/right and change the x or y velocity accordingly (i.e. you'll need two speed variables and use something similar to the code I provided to test for collision with the side of the screen).